# build.number is not fully resolved

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

**Description**

In TeamCity, I set the `{my project} > General Settings > Build number format` to the parameter %build.number%. Apparently TeamCity cannot resolve this parameter and I get `#???` as my build number and also the warning message below:

> Parameter "build.number=%build.number%" is not fully resolved, using as is.

[image]

**Question**

How can I use this parameter? Is there any special settings for that?

Basically I need the version of my project as my build number

Comment: I think you've misunderstood something here. `%build.number%` is the contents of the field you're editing there. Basically you've said "the contents of this field should be the contents of this field". No wonder TeamCity is confused. You say you want the "version of my project"? How will TeamCity figure that out? Is it the version control changeset number? If so then type in `%vcs` and wait for "intellisense" to give you the options. If you want a simple continuous number, use `%build.counter%`.

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "version of my project"?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen In our other projects in the TeamCity I see we have `Build number format = %build.number%`. Every time I build those other projects a number of this format `example: 1.0.9.12` appears under the project name (this is the version of the project, the forth part of the version is the build counter.

Comment: Where did it get 1.0.9 from?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen not entirely sure but I thought it is somehow getting it from the %build.number% parameter.

Comment: Does any of these other projects output a `##teamcity[buildNumber '1.0.9.12']` message as part of the build? Or something like `##teamcity[buildNumber '1.0.9.%build.counter%']` ?

Comment: No but I figured in the last build step, they run a bash script from a file, which stored the current and previous version of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of that field is "build.number".

Hence, you've said that the value of "build.number" should be the value of "build.number". TeamCity is thus rightly confused.

You can use `%build.number%` in the various build steps for a build configuration to refer to this field but when you're *defining* that field, you must use something else.

Comment: I've set the `Build number format` to `%build.number%`. And `%build.number%` is a predefined parameter.

Comment: And you simply cannot do that. You have a recursive definition, "the value of build.number is the value of build.number", this won't work. It isn't predefined when *you're defining it*. You've done the same as `int x = x;` in C/C++/Java/C# lingo.

Comment: What should I set it's value to have the version number ? (I want build.number to be 1.0.9.8 for example `[version].%build.counter%`

Comment: That depends entirely on where "1.0.9" comes from. Do you want to set this using TeamCity or does it come from somewhere else?